# Segmentation fault in string copying

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, strcpy

I'm getting the segmentation fault error for the inner while loop.

```
char **c;
c=(char **)malloc(3*(N-1)*sizeof(char *));

for(int i=0;i<3*(N-1);)
{
    char *temp;
    gets(temp);
    while(*temp!='$')
    {
        j=0;
        while(*temp!=' ')
        {
            *(c[i]+j)=*(temp+j);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

sorry for improper indentation.I know that manipulating char * strings would cause an error.But I am not sure about this error.I was tring to break tmp string into three different strings.

Comment: You should compile with all warnings and debugging information (e.g. with `gcc -Wall -g` on Linux) and use the debugger (e.g. `gdb` on Linux). Learning to use the debugger (and the compiler) is practically part of the learning process about programming in *C*. You may also want to use a memory leak detector like `valgrind`

Comment: You should also **avoid using `gets`, it is a *dangerous deprecated* function** (and removed from latest *C* standard). You could use `getline` or `fgets`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) `temp` should be a block of memory (buffer) to copy the `gets` string.

```
char *temp = malloc (256 * sizeof(char)); /* 256 as example*/
```

2) for the line

```
while(*temp!='$')
```

and

```
while(*temp!=' ')
```

we expect to find some incrementation for `temp` pointer (for example `temp++`) for both loops but there is not. and this cause a problem

If I can guess your need, here after a suggestion of your code fixed ( I did not test it)

```
char **c;
c=(char **)malloc(3*(N-1)*sizeof(char *));

char copy[256];
char temp[256], *p;

for(int i=0;i<3*(N-1);i++)
{
    p = temp;
    gets(p);
    while(*p!='$')
    {
        j=0;
        while(*p!=' ')
        {
            *(copy+j)=*p;
            j++;
            p++;
        }
        if(*p=='\0')
            break;
        p++;
    }
    copy[j] = '\0'
    c[i] = strdup(copy); // allocate memory with size of copy string and then copy the content of copy to allocated memory
}
```

Comment: Thanks.Can you please tell me how to input a string without knowing its size beforehand?

Answer (score 3):

You are only allocating room for `3 * (N - 1)` string pointers, but no room for the characters themselves. The `temp` pointer is also uninitialized, but you're still writing through it using `gets()`. This leads to undefined behavior.

Also, you [shouldn't cast the return value of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169), in C.

Comment: I guess we dont have to allocate space for char *

Answer (score 2):

Memory is not allocated for `temp` variable.

```
char *temp;
gets(temp);
```

Comment: yes. otherwise, pointer will be pointing to some garbage location. so when you try to reference it, segment fault occurs. Either dynamically or by static say `char temp[100];`